# Regex pattern for different language character

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex for strings below:

```
/en-us/newyork/stores.storelocation.json
/es/colecciones/víveres.storelocation.json
/es/colección/víveres%C3%ADa.storelocation.json
/fr/collections/magasins.storelocation.json
/ja/%E5%95%86%E5%93%81%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC.storelocation.json
```

I wrote it for English language
`\/en-us\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+.storelocation.json`
 but problem is it's not working with other languages like French, Chinese or Russian. And if I replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[\w]` then it considers all the character in hierarchy.

Static part of string is ".storelocation.json" and hierarchy will remain same like "/language/location/stores.storelocation.json"

Can anyone help me on this. I want a regex which will match all the strings from above.

Comment: What have you tried sofar? Show your source code

Comment: i just edit the question please check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[a-zA-Z]` use `\p{L}` to match a Unicode letter.

You can use this regex:

```
^/\p{L}{2}(?:-\p{L}{2})?/(?:\p{L}|%[A-F\d]{2})+/(?:\p{L}|%[A-F\d]{2})+\.storelocation\.json$
```

In Java use:

```
final String regex = 
"^/\\p\\{L\\}{2\\}(?:-\\p\\{L\\}{2\\})?/(?:\\p\\{L\\}|%[A-F\\d]{2})+/(?:\\p\\{L\\}|%[A-F\\d]{2})+\\.storelocation\\.json$";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rOF7kv/2)

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thanks for reply .. it's working fine except for the URL's which contains neumeric value like  /ja/%E5%95%86%E5%93%81%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC.storelocation.json

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava

Comment: In pattern, I have one doubt why you are using "?:" because pattern is working fine if i remove this also.

Comment: `(?:` is non-capturing groups. That just saves some memory while regex evaluation.